# Changing path to SDK located in different location in Visual studio

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin

When I want to run android app in Microsoft Visual Studio (with XAMARIN), I'm getting this message:

> Could not find android.jar for API Level 23. This means the Android
>   SDK platform for API Level 23 is not installed. Either install it in
>   the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or
>   change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is
>   installed.
>   (C:\Users\Tomek\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar
>   missing.)

How can I change this path to D:\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar ?
Changing location in Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android SDK location doesn't work.

Comment: you have to install and not change the path

Comment: @ColdFire, Android SDK with needed API versions is installed, I was running it in Android Studio. I decided to move them to D: from C: because my C: is a SSD 120GB disk, where I have not much more space.

Somehow when others go to for example "App.droid" > settings they have an "Application" tab, I don't. Did they move it or just its in different place now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you need to point Xamarin.Android to the location of your Android SDK on your D:\ drive:

Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android > Android SDK Location

[image]

You would set this to the path of your SDK, in your case `D:\Android\Sdk`

Please also make sure that you have the Android API 23 installed in your SDK Manager.

Go to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager

Locate the SDK Platform item in the Android 6.0 (API 23) folder and select the checkbox.  Click Install in the bottom right and follow the instructions.

[image]